# how to set a table cell to a value when next sibling td's checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

this is my code:

```
 ...
    <td class="paymentStatus">@Model.paymentStatus</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/></td>
 </tr>
```

What I'm wanting to do is that when the checkbox is checked set the paymentStatus td text to be "Payment Checked"

I tried this:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

        $(this).closest('.paymentStatus').text("Payment Checked");
    }
});
```

Doesn't work. Anyone know why and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `closest` to get to its parent `td` and then to the `sibling(td.paymentStatus)` to set the text.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HHma/)

```
$(".checkbox").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(this).closest('td')
          .siblings('td.paymentStatus')
          .text("Payment Checked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move one level up and then select the previous sibling:

```
$(this)
    .parent()
    .prev('.paymentStatus')
    .text('Payment checked');
```